# what's the difference between pos_tag and UnigramTagger and BigramTagger in nltk?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I am trying to get my hands dirty on nltk. I am referring http://victoria.lviv.ua/../NaturalLanguageProcessingWithPython.pdf. It states that `nltk.pos_tag` function assigns parts of speech to each word in the list of words, passed to it as argument.

Moving ahead, I found that there's also `nltk.DefaultTagger`, `nltk.RegexpTagger`,  `nltk.UnigramTagger` and  `nltk.BigramTagger`.

I am confused over, why we require these taggers, since `nltk.pos_tag` is doing good job of tagging parts of speech. Moreover, which tagger does `nltk.pos_tag` uses internally for tagging.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1783#issuecomment-317174189

Comment: And http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `nltk.pos_tag` is

- a pre-trained `PerceptronTagger` model
- trained on Sections 00-18 of the Wall Street Journal sections of OntoNotes 5.

The data and walk-through documentation can be found on:

- Data: https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/ldc2013t19
- Algorithm: https://explosion.ai/blog/part-of-speech-pos-tagger-in-python

---

The `UnigramTagger` and `BigramTagger` are class objects that contains no pre-trained model.

Chapter 5 of the NLTK book provides an introduction POS Tagger available http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html:

- `DefaultTagger`: Chapter 5, Section 4.1
- `RegexpTagger`: Chapter 5, Section 4.2
- `NgramTagger`: Chapter 5, Section 5.3